# Unable to SetFocus on a dynamically created text box

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am generating the text boxes dynamically.Table rows are created dynamically too, and these text boxes are added to those dynamically created row cells and they are added to the table using the following code

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    PopulateTextBoxes();
    SetFocus();
    base.OnInit(e);
}
protected void PopulateTextBoxes()
{
    int quantityRequired = 0;
    quantityRequired =GetQuantity();
    for (int j = 0; j < quantityRequired; j++)
    {
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.ID = j.ToString() +"_RowTbx"
        tb.AutoPostBack = true;
        tb.TextChanged += new EventHandler(tb_TextChanged);
        cell1.Controls.Add(tb);
        row.Cells.Add(cell1);
        TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
        CheckBox chBox = new CheckBox();
        chBox.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chBox_CheckedChanged);
        chBox.AutoPostBack = true;
        cell2.Controls.Add(chBox);
        row.Cells.Add(cell2);
        TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();
        Image img = new Image();
        img.Width = Unit.Pixel(25);
        img.Height = Unit.Pixel(25);
        img.ImageUrl = "HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath" + "/Images/" +"img.jpeg";
        cell3.Controls.Add(img);
        row.Cells.Add(cell3);
        tbl_Serial.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    LoadDataIfExists();
}

private void tb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //I have implemented code to validate the text entered in the text box.
}

protected void SetFocus()
{
    int emptytbxRow = 0;
    TextBox tbx = new TextBox();
    for (int i = 0; i < tbl_Serial.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string tbxId = i.ToString() + "_RowTbx";
        string text = ((TextBox)tbl_Serial.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl(tbxId))).Text;
        if (text == null || text==string.Empty)
        {
            tbx=((TextBox)(tbl_Serial.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl(tbxId)));
            if (tbx != null)
                tbx.Focus();
        }
    }
  protected void LoadDataIfExists()
  {
     List<string> lstData=Service.GetData(int someNum)
     for (int j = 0; j < lstData.Count; j++)
        {
            string tbxID = j.ToString() + "_RowTbx";
            TextBox tbx = (TextBox)tbl_Serial.Rows[j].Cells[0].FindControl(tbxID);
            tbx.Text = lstData[j];

        }

   }
```

When I debug, the tbx.focus seems to hit rightly but i do not see the cursor blinking on the text box in my UI.I do not know if I am missing something imp. Thank you.

Edit: Sorry I was not clear. When the page loads, the text boxes may contain data, but not all text boxes contain data. So whenever the page loads there are a few text boxes with data and there are empty ones. I want the cursor to be at the first empty box.

Comment: by focus u mean, all text in the box must be selected too?

Comment: Sorry May be i was not clear, focus meaning i would want the cursor that looks like "I" to blink on the next empty text box.

Comment: I would suggest you do this in client-side javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some unknown reason , C#code with the same logic as below did not work, while javascript works. Hope the following helps someone in future. Thank you Liqua for providing the start.

```
        window.onload = function () {
                                      FindWhichTextBoxIsEmpty();
                                    }
    function FindWhichTextBoxIsEmpty() {
        var tableSerial = document.getElementById('tbl_Serial');

        for (var i = 0; i < tableSerial.rows.length-1; i++) {

            var ID = i.toString() + "_RowTbx";
            if (document.getElementById(ID).value!="") {
                var tb = document.getElementById(ID).value;
                if (tb != "") {
                              if (i + 1 < tableSerial.rows.length-1) {
                             var nextID = (i + 1).toString() + "_RowTbx";
                             document.getElementById(nextID).focus();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you know which text box is your first empty one you want to also be aware of the page life cycle. OnInit is to early in the page life cycle for this to occur as the page is still initializing and the objects haven't yet rendered to the form. Try OnLoad or use PreRender to set focus to your item right before the form is rendered.

The link below will show you all available methods that you can hook into during the cycle.

[ASP Page Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#lifecycle_events)

Comment: Ok if thats the case then use this javascript 

window.onload=function(){
document.getElementById('<%= YourTextBox.ClientID %>').focus();

}

Answer (score 0):

didn't got your question clearly, what i got is you created a textbox dynamically, and trying to focus it at runtime.. May be this work for you try creating tb += getFocus event, or try tb.Focus();

Comment: I have that already. Kindly have a look at my code. That doesnt work.